# Printing arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, printing

I'm just now picking up C, so I'm pretty terrible since I'm coming from basic Python. I'm trying to print the elements in an array using a for-loop, but it's not coming out the right way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
  int array[]={0,1,2,3,4};
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<5;i++);
  {
      printf("%d",array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

My output is

```
134513952
```

I have no clue why it's printing this.

Comment: You don't need `<math.h>`.  You might want to separate the numbers from each other (spaces, or `%2d` or something).  And you definitely don't want to go accessing out of the bounds of your array — the semicolon after the `for` means you are accessing `array[5]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: Once you delete the extra semicolon, your output should be `01234`, which is difficult to read. You might want change your format string from `"%d"` to `" %d"`, so the numbers are shoved together.

Answer (score 7):

You have an extra semicolon.

```
 for (i=0;i<5;i++);
                  ^
                  |
        here -----+
```

That semicolon means your for loop has an empty body, and you end up printing after the loop completes, equivalently:

```
printf("%d", array[5]);
```

Since that value is beyond the end of the array, you get undefined behaviour and some strange output.

Editorial note:  You should look into a compiler that gives better warnings. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org), for example, gives this warning, even with no special flags passed:

```
example.c:7:20: warning: for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
  for (i=0;i<5;i++);
                   ^
example.c:7:20: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this
      warning
```

Answer (score 2):

Skip the semi-colon in the for-loop:

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++);
```

For your logic, you don't need a simi-colon after the for-loop.

Due to semi-colon, the for-loop is evaluated 5 times and by the time it reaches the `printf`, the value of `i` is 5. Now, trying to access the index 5 in array is giving you an unknown value since you have initialized the array with 5 values only. This can become clearer, if you were to print the value of `i` in the printf statement:

```
  for (i=0;i<5;i++);
  {
     printf("i: %d \t Val: %d",i, array[i]);
  }
```

Will give you an output such as:

```
i: 5     Val: 32767
```

Answer (score 0):

semicolon after for loop was the problem. **Before it was printing some random number, since the storage class was automatic.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
  int array[]={0,1,2,3,4};
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<5;i++);
  {
      printf("%d",array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```